# Problem in uploading of video to server in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

When I am uploading the video file to the server I sending the sample file name to it.
I am bit confused how to upload the video file with different file names.
Due to this I am getting the same video file every time.

My code is:

```
- (NSData *)generatePostDataForData:(NSData *)uploadData
{
// Generate the post header:
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"videofile.3gp\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Get the post header int ASCII format:
NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
// Generate the mutable data variable:
NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[postHeaderData length] ];
[postData setData:postHeaderData];

// Add the video:
[postData appendData: uploadData];

// Add the closing boundry:
[postData appendData: [@"\r\n--AaB03x--" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

// Return the post data:
return postData;
}
```

Guy's please help me how to get rid of this.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Chose a different filename in the header?! Modify your server-side code?!

Comment: Can u Please explain with some sample code.

Comment: Actually when uploading the video file I need to append the file name with the current date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"videofile.3gp\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

includes the filename. Chose another there.

Comment: [post appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"%@.3gp\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n",[NSDate date]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Build a NSString from the date first with an NSDateFormatter-